# Delete an entity causes Validation Error EF6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository, entity-framework-6

I'm having a strange issue when I try to delete an entity `Produto` using my repository.

**Generic Repository:**

```
public class RepositoryBase<T> : IDisposable, IRepositoryBase<T> where T : ModelBase
{
    /*Other Methods that work perfectly*/

    public virtual int Delete(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            T entity = _dataContext.Set<T>().Find(id);

            _dataContext.Set<T>().Remove(entity);

            return _dataContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch(DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Entity:**

```
public class Produto : ModelBase
{
    public virtual int? CodigoComercial { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public virtual string Nome { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(400)]
    public virtual string Ingredientes { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual CategoriaProduto Categoria { get; set; }

    public Produto()
    {
        Categoria = new CategoriaProduto();
    }
}

public class CategoriaProduto : ModelBase
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public virtual string Nome { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(400)]
    public virtual string Descricao { get; set; }
    public virtual CategoriaProduto CategoriaPai { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<OpcaoIngrediente> Opcoes { get; set; }
    public virtual CorCategoriaProdutoEnum  Cor { get; set; }
    public virtual  bool Simples { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(400)]
    public string Imagem { get; set; }

    public CategoriaProduto()
    {
        Opcoes = new List<OpcaoIngrediente>();
    }
}
```

I found the way to catch the exception, that makes no sense, I try to **Delete** the `Product`, but It claims that the `CategoriaProduto` has the Name empty and It's required. as below:

> SaborFit.Data.Model.CategoriaProduto failed validation
>
> - Nome : The field Nome is required.

I can't figure out the issue. If I try to delete the `CategoriaProduto`, all goes well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you are using `Virtual` property for most of fields, This cause to have *lazy loading* and obviously you'll encounter validation error on **Any Operation** where you call entire entity like `.Find()` operand. You must first decide what do you wanna do! Another solution that I don't prefer for you is disabling validation on save changes:

```
context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
context.SaveChanges();
```